# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context error

Tags: php

I got an error on my site.

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in
>   /home4/massspreadz/public_html/www.gamagesteelfurniture.lk/wp-content/plugins/booking/core/admin/wpbc-class-timeline.php
>   on line 1258

Here is the code that is causing the error:

```
//FixIn: 8.1.3.34
if ( ! empty( get_bk_option( 'booking_time_format') ) ) {
    $time_show = date_i18n( str_replace( ':i', '', get_bk_option( 'booking_time_format' ) ), mktime( $tt * $tm , 0, 0 ) );
    echo ( $view_days_num < 31 ) ? $time_show : '';
} else {
    echo ( ( $view_days_num < 31 ) ? ( ( ($tt*$tm) < 10?'0':'') . ($tt*$tm) . '<sup>:00</sup>' ) : '' );
}
?></div><?php
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take your time to format the question to be readable. Use the [edit] link under the question, select the code and press the `{}` button in the editor's toolbar to nicely format it as code. Before pressing `Save Edits`, check the preview under the editor to see how the question looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the following line:

```
if ( ! empty( get_bk_option( 'booking_time_format') ) ) {
```

To something like this:

```
$bkOption = get_bk_option( 'booking_time_format');

if ( ! empty( $bkOption ) ) {
```

> Note:
>
> Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will
>   result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work:
>   empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.

So, your current `php` version can't handle this. Read [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) for more information.